# How to open a specific url page every time it is reloaded from the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, web, window.location

I have a link that generates new images if you change the number at the end of the URL. I want that each time I refresh the page from the browser, it should generate a different image. I don't want to use any button to click on but to use the refresh button in the browser. I tried using the `window.onload` property but am facing some issue.

I have the code almost working and I am able to generate a new url with the random number in the end every time I refresh the page but when I try to load it's page it doesn't work. It gets stuck to the first random url. I know that the url is being changed randomly because from the alert message I can verify that. kindly help!

```
<script>
var url = "https://memegenerator.net/img/images/501.jpg";
function load()
{
    var num=url.match(/\d/g).join("");
    var numreplace=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    url=url.replace(num,numreplace);

    openpage(url);
}

function openpage(url) {
    alert(url);
    //window.location.href=url;
    //or window.location.replace(url);
}

window.onload=load();
</script>
```

I expect a new image to be loaded every time I reload the page.

Comment: Please accept if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you redirect the page to an image at another URL, for example `https://memegenerator.net/img/images/377.jpg`, so when you then refresh the page it will just refresh that URL and stay on that image. I've changed your code so that it will insert the image into the body of your page so that it will stay on your URL and do a different image every time. You can test it by pressing `Run` a few times.

```html
<body>
</body>

<head>
  <script>
    var url = "https://memegenerator.net/img/images/501.jpg"

    function load() {
      var num = url.match(/\d/g).join("")
      var numreplace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      url = url.replace(num, numreplace)

      openpage(url)
    }

    function openpage(url) {
      console.log(url)
      document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="'+url+'">'
    }

    window.onload = load()
  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert messages can prevent document to load new urls like `window.location.href`

Alert messages also prevent `form action`

So just remove `alert(url)`

Your code is working fine:

```
<script>
var url = "https://memegenerator.net/img/images/501.jpg";
function load()
{
    var num=url.match(/\d/g).join("");
    var numreplace=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    url=url.replace(num,numreplace);

    openpage(url);
}

function openpage(url) {
    window.location.href=url;
}

window.onload=load();
</script>
```

Try to short your code like this:

```
function load() {
var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000); 
var url="https://memegenerator.net/img/images/"+num+".jpg";
openpage(url);
}
```